# Properties of the Gamma function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function

I do not know much about the Gamma function, $\Gamma(n)$, except its series expansion (I am from the physics stackexchange), but I was wondering if there is a way to reduce $\Gamma(1-d/2)$ for $d\in\mathbb{C}$ (namely for $d\geq 0$) to something that looks likes $(1-d/2)\Gamma(-d/2)$? I know there are properties such as $\Gamma(n+1) = n\Gamma(n)$ but can that be used here or some factorial property?

Or is it valid, given the sign on $-d$ that I could write, $\Gamma(1-d/2) = -\frac{d}{2}\Gamma(-d/2)$ which I took from Wikipedia, $\Gamma(n+1) = n\Gamma(n)$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use $\Gamma(1+x)=x\Gamma(x)$ with $x=-d/2$. It is true for any $x\in \mathbb C$, as long as both sides are defined. You can find it on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General

Comment: @Gary Thanks! That is all I need to know!